# How do I get rid of this bump?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, faces

[image]

I want to get rid of this but the only option I can find is to delete vertices. I would appreciate some help. If needed, you can find the file at: https://pasteall.org/blend/27dda981439148c8a16237925d5b428e

Comment: You have vertices overlapping, in Edit mode select all and alt M > Merge By DIstance

Comment: Thanks again! You're a legend.